# ¿Es necesario instalar Git en Windows 10 si ya existe en Bash Ubuntu?

Tags: git, bash, windows10

Acabo de adquirir un equipo con Windows 10 (hasta ahora solo he usado Windows 7, no tuve necesidad de Windows 8 y 8.1). Lo primero que hice con este juguete nuevo fue instalarle Bash de Ubuntu. He probado este bash y está decente para ser una versión beta (voy menos de una hora, pero por lo menos para lo que hice está bien).

Ahora bien estoy instalando herramientas para el desarrollo del día a día, y estuve por descargar Git. Antes de eso, probé si Git ya estaba instalado en bash y veo que sí.

Mi pregunta: ¿es necesario instalar Git en Windows nuevamente o es suficiente usar la versión que ya existe en bash? ¿Existe algún problema al modificar los archivos, quizás el final de línea se pierda entre CR/LF y LF? ¿Existe alguna consideración que deba tener con esta decisión?

Comment: Es una cuestión un poco subjetiva. No es necesario, puedes trabajar perfectamente con la versión de git disponible en el bash de ubuntu para windows. Debes tener en cuenta que para acceder a tus ficheros mediante la ruta `/mnt/c` donde `c` es la letra de la unidad de tu disco duro. Respecto a conflictos con el salto de línea, la forma de trabajar no es diferente a cuando lo haces con Windows como pc de trabajo y un servidor linux como entorno de desarrollo o despliegue. Si lo prefieres, configura tu editor para que use saltos de línea estilo linux.

Answer (score 1):

No es necesario si tu idea es usar git directamente desde bash.

Ahora, si vas a usar algún IDE para desarrollar y querés que se integre con git entonces sí necesitás un cliente para Windows.

Yo en particular uso [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) para ver los cambios pendientes (muy útil cuando el commit tiene un tamaño interesante) integrado con [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/).

Estas herramientas mantienen los saltos de línea tal como sean definidos en el archivo.

Answer (score 1):

> ¿es necesario instalar Git en Windows nuevamente o es suficiente usar
>   la versión que ya existe en bash?

No, no es necesario, lo único es que necesitas ejecutar bash antes de poder ejecutar git (que a su vez necesita de WSL), esto lo hace un poco más tedioso de usar con herramientas de terceros.

```
> bash -c -- "git args..."
```

> ¿Existe algún problema al modificar los archivos, quizás el final de
>   línea se pierda entre CR/LF y LF? ¿Existe alguna consideración que
>   deba tener con esta decisión?

Dependerá del uso de los archivos, si quieres interoperabilidad garantizada entonces deberás utilizar \CR\LF para indicar el salto de línea. La mayoría de editores tienen herramientas para cambiar esto automáticamente, por lo que no es ningún problema.